# Use variable as define() argument

Tags: php

I'm using define function to change the nationality according to the gender (Im Italian are different by gender). The code works, but when I change the function arguments with other taken from MySQL the function stop working.

```
define("ITA", serialize(array("m" => "italiano", "f" => "italiana")));
define("ENG", serialize(array("m" => "inglese", "f" => "inglese")));
define("RUS", serialize(array("m" => "russo", "f" => "russa")));

function nationality($code, $gender) {
    $nationality = unserialize($code);
    return $nationality[$gender];
}

echo nationality(ENG,'f'); //WORKS

$nationality = $author['nationality'];
echo nationality($nationality,'f'); //DOESNT WORKS
```

EDIT: $author['nationality']; Is taken from MySQL

Comment: What is `$author['nationality']`?

Comment: That does not answer the question. What do you get if you `var_dump()` it?

Comment: @Karoly Horvath What do you mean? Wrong approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try use code:

```
define("ITA", serialize(array("m" => "italiano", "f" => "italiana")));
define("ENG", serialize(array("m" => "inglese", "f" => "inglese")));
define("RUS", serialize(array("m" => "russo", "f" => "russa")));

function nationality($code, $gender) {
    if(defined($code)) {
        $nationality = unserialize(constant($code));
        return $nationality[$gender];
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

That is because you are passing string to your function rather than a constant.

I am guessing here, but looks like `$author['nationality']` appears to be either 'ENG', 'ITA' etc. To pass string as a constant use [`constant()`](http://php.net/constant) function like this:

```
echo nationality(constant($nationality),'f');
```

Answer (score 2):

Constant like `ENG` only exist in the source file. You cannot treat them as regular strings. You never use/pass a constant, you only use/pass the mapped value.

You can use the builtin [`constant`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.constant.php) to look up the mapping:

```
constant($nationality)
```

But if all you need is to look up values by a string, store them in an `array`.

(note: there is also no need for serialization)

```
$languages = array(
    "ITA" => array("m" => "italiano", "f" => "italiana"),
    ...
);
```

and use

```
$languages[$nationality]
```